# CoordinatorLayout: Hiding/Showing half visible toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Id like to achieve a similar effect as the one you can see in **Google Play store**, where by scrolling the content the `Toolbar` goes off-screen as you scroll.

This works fine with the `CoordinatorLayout` ([1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)) introduced at **#io15**, however: If you stop the scroll "mid-way" the Toolbar remains on screen, but is cut in half: I want it to animate off-screen, just like in the Google Play store. **How can I achieve that?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now the Android Support Library 23.1.0 has a new scroll flag `SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP` which allows you to achieve this effect.

> AppBarLayout supports a number of scroll flags which affect how children views react to scrolling (e.g. scrolling off the screen). New to this release is SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP, ensuring that when scrolling ends, the view is not left partially visible. Instead, it will be scrolled to its nearest edge, making fully visible or scrolled completely off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Activity Layout file :

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now inside the activity, setup Toolbar and RecyclerView. Assign OnScrollListener to RecyclerView

```
 recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new MyScrollListener(this));
```

Extend MyScrollListerner from RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.

```
public abstract class MyScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private static final float TOOLBAR_HIDE_THRESHOLD = 10;
    private static final float TOOLBAR_SHOW_THRESHOLD = 70;

    private int mToolbarOffset = 0;
    private boolean mControlsVisible = true;
    private int mToolbarHeight;
    private int mTotalScrolledDistance;

    public MyScrollListener(Context context) {

        final TypedArray styledAttributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[]{R.attr.actionBarSize});
        mToolbarHeight = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
        styledAttributes.recycle();

        return toolbarHeight;
        mToolbarHeight = Utils.getToolbarHeight(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if(mTotalScrolledDistance < mToolbarHeight) {
                setVisible();
            } else {
                if (mControlsVisible) {
                    if (mToolbarOffset > TOOLBAR_HIDE_THRESHOLD) {
                        setInvisible();
                    } else {
                       setVisible();
                    }
                } else {
                    if ((mToolbarHeight - mToolbarOffset) > TOOLBAR_SHOW_THRESHOLD) {
                        setVisible();
                    } else {
                        setInvisible();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

        @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        clipToolbarOffset();
        onMoved(mToolbarOffset);

        if((mToolbarOffset <mToolbarHeight && dy>0) || (mToolbarOffset >0 && dy<0)) {
            mToolbarOffset += dy;
        }
        if (mTotalScrolledDistance < 0) {
            mTotalScrolledDistance = 0;
        } else {
            mTotalScrolledDistance += dy;
        }
    }

    private void clipToolbarOffset() {
     if(mToolbarOffset > mToolbarHeight) {
         mToolbarOffset = mToolbarHeight;
       } else if(mToolbarOffset < 0) {
            mToolbarOffset = 0;
        }
    }

    private void setVisible() {
        if(mToolbarOffset > 0) {
            onShow();
            mToolbarOffset = 0;
        }
        mControlsVisible = true;
    }

    private void setInvisible() {
        if(mToolbarOffset < mToolbarHeight) {
            onHide();
            mToolbarOffset = mToolbarHeight;
        }
        mControlsVisible = false;
    }

    public abstract void onMoved(int distance);
    public abstract void onShow();
    public abstract void onHide();
}
```

Comment: @zoltish Do let me know if this works for you and accept as an answer if it does. :)

Comment: the appbar/toolbar can be scrolled without scrolling the RecyclerView in which case the listener code won't be triggered. This happens when the RecyclerView is at the top and has nothing to scroll up, and the user pulls down, this will cause a scrolling of the entire CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the AppBarLayout seems to be a better solution, as there are two possible scroll-events - of the entire CoordinatorLayout, and of the RecyclerView/NestedScrollView

See this answer as a possible working code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32110089/819355