# How do I make the RecyclerView stay still when the app bar snaps?

Tags: android, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

When the AppBarLayout snaps, the CoordinatorLayout scrolls the RecyclerView up. Instead, I want the AppBarLayout snap back into place without changing the scroll position of the RecyclerView. The Google Play Store app has the behavior I am trying to achieve.

How do I accomplish keeping the RecyclerView still while the AppBarLayout snaps?

Here is my layout:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: like this? https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a602b0cdf643d63a1903dccca209b4ff99530b5d/687474703a2f2f692e67697068792e636f6d2f336f456475546950744a47473951323358712e676966

Comment: yes, just like that. Is the source available for that?

Comment: Look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737589/how-to-make-recycler-view-not-scroll-when-appbar-snaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Retractable Toolbar](https://github.com/michelelacorte/RetractableToolbar)

In your `build.grade` add:

```
compile 'it.michelelacorte.retractabletoolbar:library:1.0.0'
```

Than in your `Activity` (change recyclerView and toolbar with yours):

```
RetractableToolbarUtil.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener showHideToolbarListener;
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(showHideToolbarListener = new RetractableToolbarUtil.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener(toolbar));

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            showHideToolbarListener.onRestoreInstanceState((RetractableToolbarUtil.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener.State) savedInstanceState
                    .getParcelable(RetractableToolbarUtil.ShowHideToolbarOnScrollingListener.SHOW_HIDE_TOOLBAR_LISTENER_STATE));
}
```

Result:

[image]